# Solution to a certain moment problem

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions

I'm looking for a function $f$ that satisfies

1. $f(x)\geq0$
2. $\int f(x) \mathrm{d}x=1$
3. $\int xf(x) \mathrm{d}x=0$
4. $\int x^2f(x)\mathrm{d}x=1$
5. $\int x^4f(x)\mathrm{d}x=\delta$
6. $\int x^5f(x)\mathrm{d}x=\infty$
7. It has a "nice" antiderivative, not like the density of the Student's $t$-distribution with 5 degrees of freedom and not like a series.

So basically I'm looking for a density $f$ that solves this truncated moment problem.

My approach so far was to start with the right side of the real line:$$f_+(x)=\frac{1}{(x+\rho_1)(x+\rho_2)^2(x+\rho_3)^3}, x\geq0 $$
Then I would solve for $\rho_1,\rho_2,\rho_2$ such that $\frac{1}{2}$ of the specified moments are matched. Later I would get my $f$ by replacing $(\cdot)$ by $|\cdot|$. However, I run into ugly lengthy partial fraction decompositions and ugly integrals. Are there more accessible approaches than these rational functions?

Comment: What is the interval over which you take these integrals?

Comment: @wordsthatendinGRY: Due to condition (6) and (2) it must be an infinite domain. Due to (3) it must involve both ends of the real line. Am I wrong? In the end, it doesn't really matter. In my approach I considered $f_+$ first to get rid of condition (3). Then my solution would be symmetric, but also assymetric solutions are appreciated.

Comment: Is $\delta$ just an arbitrary number?

Comment: One natural way to start is by restricting to an even $f$ since then the odd moments (if they exist) must vanish. However condition (6) cannot hold in this case so do you need the integral to be $\infty$ or is 'the integral does not exist (converge)' also OK?

Comment: @frank000: Yes, $\delta > 1$.

Comment: @Winther: Yes, it is OK if the integral does not exist.

Comment: Played a bit with it in Mathematica: A function like $f(x)= \frac{16 a^{7/2} \left(b x^2+1\right)}{\pi  (a b+5) \left(a+x^2\right)^4}$ on $(-\infty,\infty)$ with $a = 3-\sqrt{9-\delta}$ and $b = \frac{-\sqrt{9-\delta } \delta -7 \delta +25 \sqrt{9-\delta }+75}{\delta ^2-5   \delta }$ has all the desired properties (plus fairly simple closed form antiderivative) however it only works for $\delta \in [5,9]$.

Comment: I failed with maxima. So Mathematica is more powerfull. Unfortunately, I was looking for $\delta$ around 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set $f(x)=1/x^6$ for $x\ge m>0$ then you have taken care of the tail. The remaining conditions can be met by a polynomial of degree 4 on $-m\le x\le m$ with $f(x):=0$ for $x<-m$.  However, the condition $f(x)\ge 0$ discards many solutions. In general, $m$ will depend on $\delta$. Another way of obtaining a solution is to define $f$ constant on certain intervals. For example, if $\delta=3$ you can set $m=1$ and
$$
f(x):=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }\qquad\quad\ x<-3\\
\frac{2}{75}&\text{if }\ -3\le x<-2\\
\frac{3}{25}&\text{if }\ -2\le x<-1\\
\frac{33}{100}&\text{if }\ -1\le x<0\\
\frac{97}{300}&\text{if }\ \quad\ 0\le x<1\\
\frac{1}{x^6}&\text{if }\ \ \quad 1\le x
\end{cases}
$$

Moreover, you can construct solutions that are $C^{\infty}$, approximating the locally constant solutions by such functions.

${\bf{EDIT:}}$ Playing around with the limits and locally constant functions one can set for example
$$
f(x):=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }\qquad\quad\ x<-2\delta\\
\frac{k}{6\delta^6}&\text{if }\ -2\delta\le x<-\delta\\
a&\text{if }\ 0\le |x|<1\\
b&\text{if }\ \quad\ 1\le |x|<(\delta+1)/2\\
c&\text{if }\ \quad\ (\delta+1)/2\le |x|<\delta\\
\frac{k}{x^6}&\text{if }\ \ \quad \delta\le x
\end{cases}
$$
Then $a,b,c$ can be determined by the conditions 2., 4. and 5. If one set $k:=\delta^2/800$, then $a,b,c$ are positive for 
$\delta\in[1.0026,6.9]$.